# Como saber se o usuário clicou fora do AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Minha dúvida é bem simples, porém não estou encontrando algo que possa utilizar.

No meu projeto android, eu verifico a conexão do GPS do aparelho do usuário, e se caso não está ativo, peço em um caixa de dialog para que ele ative, com dois botões, cancelar e configurações.

O evento dos botões estão corretos, porém como saber se o usuário ao invés de clicar em alguns dos botões, clique fora do alertDialog, ou seja, em qualquer espaço da tela ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível tornar o *AlertDialog* *Modal* isto é não ser possível sair do *dialog* sem que o utilizador escolha um dos botões:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setCancelable(false);
.....
.....
builder.show();
```

Outra forma é permitir que o *AlertDialog* possa ser cancelado, intersetar esse evento e agir de acordo.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        // Faça aqui o que pretende quando o dialog é cancelado
        }
    });
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, isso mesmo que estava querendo, mais uma vez, obrigado !